# Non Jews: What honor to give a non jewish father at an Orthodox bar mitzvah (Jewish son) or at a wedding?

Tags: gentiles, marriage, bar-bas-bat-mitzvah

I have heard from an active Rabbi that he would give a non Jewish father the honor of opening  the ark. What about putting on a Torah covering? Where is this issue discussed in  halachic sources? Due to the increase in mixed marriages ,this is an increasing issue also in weddings.

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya.  A wedding and a bar mitzvah are pretty different in content and purpose, so it might be better to focus this question on one or the other.  (You could then ask the other question separately, though I recommend waiting to see what you learn from the answers to the first that might bear on the other.)

Comment: I am assuming that you mean a wedding of a person with a non-Jewish father. Since that is a bizayon, I do not think that the person involved (the boy or the bride or groom) should be shamed by having it publicly acknowledged.

Comment: Note that this does not say who the *rabbi* is or where he is speaking about doing this.