# May a non-Jew participate in certain shul "honors"?

Tags: tefilla, gentiles, synagogue, honors

Can a non-Jew participate in any of these shul honors?

- opening / closing the ark
- carrying the Torah to / from the bimah
- hagbah (lifting the Torah) and / or gelilah (wrapping the Torah)
- reciting / leading the singing of the ending prayer songs such as "Adon Olam" / "Yigdal"
- gabbai (to distribute aliyot and other honors to other congregants and / or as one of those next to the Torah reader to correct possible mistakes)

The commonality in most of the above is that they do not involve the recital of congregational prayers. Adon Olam / Ygdal are at the end of the service, and from what I understand, supplements that are not considered the main part of Musaf.

Comment: Realted: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/76567/non-jews-what-honor-to-give-a-non-jewish-father-at-an-orthodox-bar-mitzvah-jew

Comment: http://www.chabad.org/multimedia/media_cdo/aid/1291596/jewish/How-to-Do-the-Lifting-of-the-Torah.htm  - see answer posted July 24, 2012

Comment: My inclination would be that it would be a bizui (insult) to the Torah and the congregation. However I do not have a source.

Comment: @sabbahillel Why are non-Jews insulting to the Torah?

Comment: @DoubleAA - the Torah was not given to the non-Jews so having a non-Jew lift the Torah when there is a Jew present would be very insulting since it would be as if the Jew didn't care much for his gift (my opinion)

Comment: @EzraHoerster reasonable analysis. However, the Torah was also translated into 70 languages, which seems to be an indication that G-d wanted to make it available to non-Jews to learn from it.

Comment: @DanF - learn from it yes pick it up when there are other Jews around no. and also the Torah has been translated for Jews who don't speak Hebrew, not technically for the nations

Answer (score 2):

Take care: the quoted answer below from Rabbi Posner refers directly only to hagbah and he gives no source for his answer.

---

[Chabad](http://www.chabad.org/multimedia/media_cdo/aid/1291596/jewish/How-to-Do-the-Lifting-of-the-Torah.htm) have an article on hagbah.

Someone commented on the article asking,

> is a non jewish person allowed to do hagbah
>
> I belong to a very small shul that only gets a minyan when we are
>   lucky on Saturday morning. But, we get some people that are not Jewish
>   who come to our shul on a regular basis, and are married to one of our
>   congregant who is Jewish. Can they be allowed to do Hagbah or Galleh.
>   In Mishneh Torah Chapter 10 Halacha 8 seems to allow this. Please
>   respond as we are having a meeting this Thursday night about this
>   subject.

But Rabbi Menachem Posner answers:

> As you quote Maimonides, he does write that a non-Jew may hold a
>   Torah. However, hagbah is part of the Jewish synagogue service, and
>   that is something that must only be performed by a Jewish person.

The implication is that anything that is part of the Jewish synagogue service must only be performed by a Jewish person.